# rsync files from different path

Tags: linux, path, rsync

I need to copy files from remote server (different path) to local path

Iget file list in this working way:

```
ssh user@remote " ls -R /path/  \
" |grep "o1_" | awk -F '_' '{if ($4 > 55146) print $0}'  >file_list.txt
```

or

```
ssh user@remote " find /path/  " \
|grep "o1_" | awk -F '_' '{if ($8 > 55152) print $0}' >files_full_path.txt
```

example files_full_path.txt

```
/path/path1/file1 
/path/path1/file2
/path/path2/file3 
/path/path2/file4
```

I've tried with full or non full path without success,  examples below:

```
rsync -aver --include-from=files_full_path.txt user@remote:/path/ /destination_path

rsync -ave --include-from=files_full_path.txt --include /path/ --exclude='/*/' /path/
```

Can you help me?

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify what the problem is.  What happens with your commands?  Why can't you just do `rsync user@remote:"$(cat files_full_path.txt)"`?

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't work: the first file in the list has been copied but the others are not copied.

rsync user@host:"$(cat to_apply.txt)" ./
bash: line 1: :/PATH/file.ext: No such file or directory
rsync error: remote command not found (code 127) at main.c(1651) [generator=3.1.2]
/PATH/file.ext is substitute of a existing remote file

Comment: Well, to_apply.txt is not the file name you used in your question.  Update question if needed.  Also, try out the answer that I supplied below and comment on it as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will help you:

```
$ ssh user@remote touch 1 2
$ mkdir 12
$ echo -e "1\n2" | rsync --include-from=- user@remote:\* 12/
$ ls 12 | cat
1
2
```

Answer (score -1):

I'have found solution

cat to_apply.txt |xargs -i scp user@host:{} destination_path/

Comment: You asked about rsync but your answer is using scp?!

Comment: Having achieved the purpose scp or rsync  is the same.